# An error occured while executing the query. Please check the stack trace for more detail

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to query a customer in qbo with a name that has an ' for example (Joe's Shop) and getting the above error.

here is the code.

```
        IEnumerable<Customer> customers = customerQueryService.Where(c => c.DisplayName =="Joe's Shop");
        if (customers.Count()!=0 )
        {
            customer = customers.First();
        }

        return customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use backslash to escape the single quote.

"Joe\'s Shop"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
using Intuit.Ipp.Core;
using Intuit.Ipp.Data;
using Intuit.Ipp.LinqExtender;
using Intuit.Ipp.QueryFilter;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

static class SampleCalls
{
public static Customer QueryCustomerByDisplayName(ServiceContext context, string displayName) {
    displayName = displayName.Replace("'", "\\'"); //Escape special characters
    QueryService<Customer> customerQueryService = new QueryService<Customer>(context);
    return customerQueryService.Where(m => m.DisplayName == displayName).FirstOrDefault();
}
}
```